# How to copy an element from another table if they share one common element in a column

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table containing two columns : Fruits & Color

| Fruits | Color |
| --- | --- |
| Apple | Red |
| Orange | Orange |
| grape | NULL |

On the other hand, i have another table, with only fruits, and an empty Color column.

| Fruits | Color |
| --- | --- |
| banana | NULL |
| Orange | NULL |
| grape | NULL |

My goal here is to parse the complete first table, and to add in the second one the color if the fruits are the same. To get something like this for my second table :

| Fruits | Color |
| --- | --- |
| banana | NULL |
| Orange | Orange |
| grape | NULL |

I've tried something like this, but it would only add into the second db all the rows from the first one that matches the same fruits

```
insert into "secondtable" (color)
select color
from "completetable" t1
where not exists (select 1 from "secondtable" t2 where t2.fruits = t1.fruits)
```

Comment: What you describe is an `UPDATE` (not `INSERT`), since you are changing values in existing rows and not adding new ones..

Comment: Do you really mean database? Is one table in a MySQL database and the other in a PostgreSQL database? Or is both the wording and the tags a mistake and you are talking about two tables in the same database? If so, which DBMS? MySQL or PostgreSQL?

Comment: And you want to **update** existing rows, yes? You don't want to **insert** new rows. Correct?

Comment: MySQL or PostgreSQL? Select actual DBMS and remove wrong tag.

Comment: @PM77-1 Indeed!
And the tag was mistaken, it has been changed

Comment: Are you going to keep both tables? Why don't you want Apple in your second table?

Comment: @jarlh. Yep, i want one table containing all of the fruits, and another table with some of those fruits. The goal is the take the color of the fruit from the first table into the second one

Comment: Then you want `UPDATE`, not `INSERT`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to want to update all rows of the second table with the values from the first table. As all fruits are null in the second table, you can simply

```
update secondtable
set color = (select color from firsttable where firsttable.fruit = secondtable.fruit);
```

That makes some unnecessary updates where null remains null, but is quick to write and understand.

Answer (score 0):

Specially on postgresql (and some other) also works and don't make unnecessarey updates:

```sql
UPDATE secondtable SET color = firsttable.color
FROM secondtable
  JOIN firsttable ON firsttable.fruit = secondtable.fruit
WHERE secondtable.color IS NULL AND firsttable.color IS NOT NULL;
```